# Storing huge number of entities in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following scenario: I am building a dummy web app that pulls betting odds every minute, stores all the events, matches, odds etc. to the database and then updates the UI.

I have this structure: **Sports** > **Events** > **Matches** > **Bets** > **Odds** and I am using code first approach and for all DB-related operations I am using EF.

When I am running my application for the very first time and my database is empty I am receiving XML with odds which contains: ***~16 sports, ~145 events, ~675 matches, ~17100 bets & ~72824 odds***.

Here comes the problem: how to save all this entities in timely manner? Parsing is not that time consuming operation - 0.2 seconds, but when I try to bulk store all these entities I face memory problems and the save took more than 1 minute so next odd pull is triggered and this is nightmare.

I saw somewhere to disable the `Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` and recreate my context on every 100/1000 records I insert, but I am not nearly there. Every suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: "but I am not nearly there" meaning have you tried it and seen it didn't do much? I personally faced similar issues with bulk operations, while `Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnable` and recreating context helped a bit, I found a different way entirely.

Answer (score 1):

When you are inserting huge (though it is not that huge) amounts of data like that, try using [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx). You can also try using [Table Value Parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) and pass it to a stored procedure but I do not suggest it for this case as TVPs perform well for records under 1000. `SqlBulkCopy` is super easy to use which is a big plus.

If you need to do an update to many records, you can use `SqlBulkCopy` for that as well but with a little *trick*. Create a staging table and insert the data using `SqlBulkCopy` into the staging table, then call a stored procedure which will get records from the staging table and update the target table. I have used `SqlBulkCopy` for both cases numerous times and it works pretty well.

Furthermore, with `SqlBulkCopy` you can do the insertion in batches as well and provide feedback to the user, however, in your case, I do not think you need to do that. But nonetheless, this flexibility is there.

> Can I do it using EF only?

I have not tried but there is [this](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com) library you can try.

Comment: Using SqlBulkCopy I was able to store the 80k bulk of entities for 1.8 seconds, but since this is not part of EF can I do it using only EF?

Comment: EF doesn't have direct support for bulk operations, but you can purchase a library that adds such capability.  It's called "Entity Framework Extensions".  Or you can write your own, like I did.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your situation but:

> All actions you've been doing it all depends on your machine specs and
>   the software itself.
>
> Now if machine specs cannot handle the process it will be the time to
>   change a plan like to limit the count of records to be inserted till
>   it all to be done.